# Git for windows outputting crlf line endings

Tags: windows, bash, git

I am attempting to compare an output with an expected output.

```
$python <program> < input.txt > output.txt

$diff expected.txt output.txt
```

My expected output has lf endings (As it should for all unix terminals.) This comparison works whenever i use a true unix terminal.
But on my home desktop, which runs windows and git bash, this comparison fails on every line - the output file is constructed with crlf endings.

I have set auto.crlf to false, and even tried reinstalling git and adjusting file checkout settings, but I have had no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use msys2 with git package.

Comment: If your `diff` implementation has the `-b` switch, use it.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `git config -l`?